# How to change lock screen wallpaper in macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, lockscreen

Is it possible to change lock screen (not login screen, I mean the one triggered by Ctrl+Cmd+Q) wallpaper to different one than desktop wallpaper?

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible on macOS.

*Extra info: It may be different if you have a screensaver running and then you open the login menu.*

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the screensaver